# type of numbers that are not stored in a variable

Tags: c

I'm a Little confused about some numbers in C-Code. I have the following piece of Code

```
int k;
float a = 0.04f;

for (k=0; k*a < 0.12; k++) {
  * do something *
}
```

in this case, what is the type of "0.12" ? double ? float ? it has never been declared anywhere. Anyways, in my program the Loop above is excuted 4 times, even though 3*0.04=0.12 < 0.12 is not true. Once I Exchange 0.12 with 0.12F (because I am globally restricted to float precision in all of the program), the Loop is now executed 3 times. I do not understand why, and what is happening here. Are there any proper Guidelines on how to write such statements to not get unexpected issues?

Another related issue is the following: in the Definition of variables, say

```
float b = 1/180 * 3.14159265359;
```

what exactly "is" "1" in this case ? and "180" ? Integers ? Are they converted to float numbers ? Is it okay to write it like that ? Or should it be "1.0f/180.0f*3.14159265359f;"

Last part of the question,

if i have a fuction

```
void testfunction(float a)
```

which does some things.

if I call the fuction with testfunction(40.0/6.0), how is that Division handled ? It seems that its calculated with double precision and then converted to a float. Why ?

That was a Long question, I hope someone can help me understand it.

Comment: You should try your angle answer and see what result you get for b when you use intergers versus floats. You're asking about number literals.

Comment: Types of numeric constants are described in section 6.4.4. Conversions are in 6.3. [C11 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) I'd recommend trying to read it; I found it to be not nearly as scary as I expected.

Comment: There are 3 distinct questions, not one.

Answer (score 3):

> *...numbers that are not stored in a variable*

They are called "constants".

- Any unsuffixed **floating point constant** has type `double`.

  Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.4.4.2

  > An unsuffixed floating constant has type `double`. If suffixed by the letter `f` or `F`, it has
  >   type `float`. If suffixed by the letter `l` or `L`, it has type `long double`.
- For Integer constants, the type will depend on the value.

  Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.4.4.1,

  > The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can
  >   be represented. [..]

  and for unsuffixed decimal number, the list is

  > ```
  > int
  > long int
  > long long int
  > ```

Regarding the mathematical operation accuracy of floating point numbers, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/2173917)

Answer (score 1):

"0.12" is a constant, and yes, without a trailing f or F, it will be interpreted as a double.

That number can not be expressed exactly as a binary fraction. When you compare `k * a`, the result is a float because both operands are floats. The result is slightly less than 0.12, but when you compare against a double, it gets padded out with zeros to the required size, which increases the discrepancy. When you use a float constant, the result is not padded (cast), and by good luck, comes out exactly equal to the binary representation of "0.12f". This would likely not be the case for a more complicated operation.

Comment: I think the standard mentions it as constant, rather that literal..for integer and floating points, is not it?

Comment: @Sourav. You're right. Updated

Answer (score 0):

if we use a fractional number for eg, like `3.4` it's default type if double. You should explicitly specify it like `3.4f` if you want it to consider as single precision (float).
if you call the following function

```
int fun()
{
    float a= 1.2f;
    double b = 1.2;

    return (a==b);
}
```

this will always return zero (false).because before making comparison the float type is converted to double (lower type to higher type) , At this time sometimes it can't reproduce exact 1.2, a slight variations in value can be happen after 6th position from decimal point. You can check the difference by the following print statement

```
printf("double: %0.9f \n float: %0.9f\n",1.2,1.2f);
```

It results ike

```
double: 1.200000000
float: 1.200000481
```